# loop with lambda expression, using loop variable inside lambda

Tags: java, events, minecraft

So I have this code: (Spigot API)

```
setSkullItem(i, head, player ->{
    clearSlots();
    save(itemNr);
});
itemNr++;
```

It's basicly doing this:
I loop through the skullitems I have, i is where I place the item in an inventory, head is the icon(Itemstack) to display and then the player ->{} is when a player clicks the item.

My issue is the following:
When I loop through them I need to get the itemNr of the item that was looped however this does not allow me todo so. instead if I run the code and there are 4 items in the inventory and I click any of them it will allways grab the last itemNr when running the command inside the click event (player -> {}).

Anyone able to help me figure out a way to get around this?

Keep in mind:
I am a mediocre java developer trying to learn java while doing this. I can't figure out what it's called when you have code running like this: (player -> {})

Thanks in advance,
Thomas

Comment: Its called a **lambda** expression.

Comment: Thank you @GhostCat Using gooogle right now to look for an answer but have found none so far, all I found was that it needs to be effectivly final  variables inside the lambda... is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it using the following:

```
int index = itemNr;
setSkullItem(i, head, player ->{
    clearSlots();
    save(index);
});
itemNr++;
```